# PL/SQL: PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

multiple_pkg_3.sub_proc_insert insert the data into table person_name. When compiling, ORA-00942: table or view does not exist is shown in the select statement.

```
   PROCEDURE chk_pkg_1 IS
        p_name VARCHAR2(25);
        exp_id NUMBER;
   BEGIN
        i11137.multiple_pkg_3.sub_proc_insert(v_name);
        SELECT id INTO exp_id FROM i11137.person_name WHERE name = v_name;
        ut.expect(exp_id).to_equal(act_id);
   END chk_pkg_1;
```

The select statement works outside the procedure.

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: The select statement works outside the procedure.